# fstab prevents successful reboot, how to automate mounting external HD?

Tags: linux, fstab

I’m a semi-experienced Linux admin who’s trying to figure out how to automount an external hard drive to my Linux box.  (ver 2.6.16.13-4-smp)  (Its an older box, I know.)  I can manually mount the drive just fine:

```
me@linux:/> mount /dev/sdc1 /media/Seagate
me@linux:/>
```

meaning I want to mount the device located at `/dec/sdc1` to directory `/media/Seagate`.  This works just great.  When I do this, I see the following:

```
me@linux:/> df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...other stuff...
/dev/sdc1             917G   13G  858G   2% /media/Seagate
me@linux:/>
```

Trouble is, I need the machine to do this automatically whenever it reboots.  I’ve Googled around and learned a bit about the `/etc/fstab` file.  To that end, I’ve added this line at the end of my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/sdc1            /media/Seagate       ext3       defaults              0 2
```

The previous admin had left a commented-out line in `/etc/fstab` which once worked.  I cloned it, edited it for my external HD, and then let ‘er rip.  The “ext3” comes from that line, I’m not sure what it does.  The “defaults” and “0 2” were suggested as the simplest implementation from a few tutorials I found online.

So when I rebooted my machine with the above line in `/etc/fstab`, the machine did ***not*** successfully reboot.  When I checked the monitor, there were a number of error messages, including:

```
Waiting for /dev/sdc1
error on stat() /dev/sdc1: No such file or directory
fsck.ext3: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:  The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
```

A photo of the full monitor screen is below.

I’m not sure what’s going on here, but it looks like my Linux box tries to mount the external HD, the HD is not available, so the Linux box does not successfully boot?  But the HD is plugged in at the time of reboot.

If I remove the one line I added and reboot again, the system comes up fine, but then I have to manually mount the HD.

So… any idea what’s going on here?  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What filesystem does your external drive actually have? You should be able to see this in the output of `mount` (no arguments) when the disk is mounted, after mounting it manually.

Comment: You can also issue `blkid` in root mode to check the UUID, sometimes the /dev/sdX devices numbers change and it is a good practice to put the UUID instead of the /dev/sdX name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `/etc/fstab` file.  The last number on each line is **fs_passno**.  If that is set to 1 (true) then it is required for a successful boot that fsck run and successfully complete on the given device..  If you have that `/dev/sdc1` line in your `/etc/fstab` with the last number on that line a 1 then that device needs to be present during boot, otherwise boot will be halted as shown by your pic.

Change that 1 to a 0 to allow that /dev/sdc1 line to be present in `fstab` without the usb device being plugged in, or go remove that line entirely from fstab if the usb device is not plugged in, or have the usb device plugged in and able to pass fsck if you are going to maintain that 1 on the end of the line in fstab.

I'm not sure if the value for fs_passno has different affects over different linux distributions, other than making it a 0 means don't fsck.

Also, your mounting *by-name* having `/dev/sdc1` in the first column in fstab.  I strongly recommend mounting by any other means, preferably *by-uuid*.  Mounting by-name is not robust, and your external disk might be `sdc` now but can easily become something else if any other hardware changes causing other problems.

Answer (score 1):

## Upgrade your system

This is a known bug ([Bug 204396 - kernel does not see usb thumb drive during boot](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=204396)) in a kernel version close to the one you are using.

Upon a glance, the issues seems to be somewhere between automatic loading of modules and udev. Workarounds may exist and you may try them. Adding `mount /dev/sdc1 /media/Seagate` to your `/etc/rc.local` could help. I really recommend you to switch to a newer kernel, though. It will be far less cumbersome (provided you do not rely on this specific version).